# vector of atomics in c++: msvc vs gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, visual-c++, atomic

I developed some code on Linux which uses a `std::vector` of `std::atomic` variables - one for each thread that I use, which might be set to a different number for some different computation. In simple form it looked something like:

Edit: also including a reset function:

```
class threadsafe_vals{
    std::vector<std::atomic<int> > vals;
public:
    threadsafe_vals(int _n){
        vals = std::vector<std::atomic<int> >(_n);
        for (auto &x:vals){
            x=0;
        }
    }
    void reset(int _i){
        vals =std::vector<std::atomic<int> >(n);
        for (auto &x:vals){
            x=0;
        }
    }
    int get(int _i){ return vals[_i];}
    void set(int _i,in _val){ vals[_i] = _val;}
};
```

I know that `std::atomic`s have no copy constructor so I made sure I never used anything like `erase` `push_back` etc. etc., but simply treated the vector as a fixed array until I reset the whole thing. And whenever I reset the vector I always did so using the line `vals = std::vector<std::atomic<int> >(n)` such that the use of the copy constructor was avoided, and instead the existing atomics destructed and then simply initialised (I think). The code was not required to be threadsafe during the `reset(int n)` operation.

Anyway, for both Linux using `gcc` and Mac using Clang, this all worked.

I then however, tried to port my code to Windows under MSVC, and it won't compile.

I now get the compiler error

```
std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int> &): attempting to reference a deleted function
```

in file `xmemory()`.

It looks like it is complaining that it is having to use the copy-constructor for the `atomics` I am using.

Now: gcc and clang were both smart enough to figure out I didn't actually use the copy constructor and compiled my code, so I'm assuming that this is a Microsoft c++ implementation thing.

But then the questions remains:

1. Why does MSVC think I'm invoking the copy constructor here?
2. More crucially, how I can I get the desired effect whereby I can have a vector of atomics without invoking the copy constructor according to MSVC (or any other method), similar to my original code, in a portable way?

I've tried searching for some similar questions, but the answers seem all over the place with some stating that vectors of atomics simply aren't possible. But this is false, at least according to the gcc and clang interpretations of the c++ standard.

Comment: Copy right here: `vals = std::vector<std::atomic<int> >(_n);` Instead do : `threadsafe_vals(int _n): vals(_n)` and make use of the member initializer list.

Comment: Ah sorry, there is another function I use in addition which resets the `vals` vector. Will edit

Comment: not sure how you use the vector, but the elements are atomic, the vector is not. Eg `reset(int i)` isnt threadsafe at all

Comment: You can use `unique_ptr<T[]>` for dynamic array of types that cannot be copied or move

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know. That's why I wrote "The code was not required to be threadsafe during the reset(int n) operation"

Comment: sorry, missed that

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number nw.

Comment: @user4581301 I have implemented what you suggest and avoid the reset function, but I still get the same error, but now from the `xutility` file

Comment: I hate it when that happens. Somewhere else in your program you accidentally trigger another copy, but this time it's because you called something that called something that... and ultimately it got to a function in xutility that tried to copy the atomic. In the full build output there may be a *Invoked from here: <location in you code, hopefully>* message that can help you track down the culprit.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to use `vector` at all, since you know you won't be able to use practically any of its features.  What does it buy you that a plain array would not?

Comment: @NateEldredge I simply want a container that can be (repeatedly) initialised to some length at runtime - i.e. I don't know what that number is and the user needs to specify it

Comment: @user4581301 Ok, so I think it is because I am invoking the copy assignment operator for my class elsewhere. I'm struggling to think of a good way to reset the vals container without invoking the copy-ctors of its elements. Note I can't use initialisation lists in copy assignment operators.

Comment: So then @AlexGuteniev's suggestion of a `unique_ptr` seems more appropriate, as it does precisely that.  Even a raw pointer and allocating space with `new[]` would solve your problem.  The functionality of `vector` that it lacks (adding, removing, resizing on the fly) is the functionality you can't use anyway.

Comment: I'm not certain, but the difference between MSVC and GCC here may be [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  With C++17 some forms of copy elision became mandatory, but I'm not sure offhand whether that applies to your code, and anyway you've tagged this C++11.